# Why is there a mismatch in MapReduce input records value in MR job log and actual number of records passed in input file?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a `Mapreduce` program to find the user who performed the transactions summing up to the maximum amount for each year.

I've passed the input file to the program containing records with number of rows `= 1048576`

However, on running the program, the job logs show `mapreduce` input records `= 1228500`

I am unable to understand why there is a mismatch in the number of records.

Input Data Sample -

```
    1,500,2000
    1,200,2000
    2,2000,2000
    1,200,2001
    1,800,2001
    2,200,2001
    1,500,2000
    1,200,2000
    2,2000,2000
    1,200,2001
    1,800,2001
```

Format is - UserID, TransactionAmount, Year and number of records in the file is 1048576

MR Job log shows -

```
Map-Reduce Framework
Map input records=1228500
Map output records=1228500
Map output bytes=14742000
Map output materialized bytes=1087526
Input split bytes=98
```

**MapReduce Code -**

```
public static class TransactionMap extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,UserDetails>
        {
              public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                  String line = value.toString();
                  String keyValue[] = line.split(",");
                  IntWritable year = new IntWritable();
                   UserDetails user = new UserDetails(Integer.parseInt(keyValue[0]),Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1]));
                  year.set(Integer.parseInt(keyValue[2]));
                  context.write(year,user);
              }
        }

        public  static  class TransactionReduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, UserDetails, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
            public  void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<UserDetails> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                HashMap<Integer,Integer> user2AmtMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
                IntWritable maxUser = new IntWritable();
                for (UserDetails val : values)
                {
                        if(user2AmtMap.containsKey(val.getUserID())){
                            user2AmtMap.put(val.userID,user2AmtMap.get(val.userID)+val.amount);
                        }
                    else
                            user2AmtMap.put(val.userID,val.amount);
                }
                int maxAmount = Collections.max(user2AmtMap.values());
                int maxUserID = 0;
                for(HashMap.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : user2AmtMap.entrySet()){
                    if(entry.getValue() == maxAmount)
                        maxUserID = entry.getKey();
                }
                maxUser.set(maxUserID);
                context.write(key,maxUser);

            }
```

Comment: Without knowing your input format, or seeing the code, it's hard to say. Also, please copy the terminal output as text, not an image

Comment: Please show your Job definition as well

Comment: You mean the main method where I have defined the job and done mapping etc?

Comment: Try to use a  java file reader  to read  and split    again ,  some data format may split to two lines

Comment: IMO, then you might look into your output. We don't have clue about your complete input data. But, if you getting mismatch number of count, then you could probably look for output

Comment: Sure if the main method you created a Job object and are waiting for its completion... It doesn't need to be in main method, therefore I said "job definition "

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "lowestTransaction");
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(UserDetails.class);
job.setMapperClass(TransactionMap.class);
job.setReducerClass(TransactionReduce.class);
 job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

Comment: job.setJarByClass(LowestTransaction.class);
 job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename" , args[2]);
 job.waitForCompletion(true);